# how can I use line break without any tag in html?

Tags: html, reactjs, break

I want to return some results in my react code by using ajax, now I should use line break in my second page and return the result but i cant use `<br/>` because my result shows tags like this : `hi br/ hi`. How can I insert line break without any html tag?
my ajax code :

```
 $.ajax({
    'async': false,
    'type': "POST",
    'global': false,
    'dataType': 'html',
    'url': "barRules.bc",
    'data': { 'id': JSON.stringify(id)  },
    'success':(response)=>{
        tmp = response;
    }
});
```

my second page : "  @Field : br/  @value /  "

Comment: \n ?..............

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space#Values) css property and set it to `pre-line` so that new lines are preserved in the html.

```
.keep-new-line{
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```